# Why I don't see gem list after correctly installed rbenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I installed `rbenv` using `homebrew` and installed `2.0.0p347` after that I run `bundle install` in my project folder and my gems installed to `vendor/bundle`. But when I run `gem list` I don't see them.

myproject(development)» rbenv versions
  system
* 2.0.0-p247 (set by /Users/rege/Code/myproject/.ruby-version)

I also run `rbenv rehash`

My configuration:

```
~» echo $PATH.
/Users/rege/.gem/bin:/Users/rege/.rbenv/shims:/Users/rege/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/rege/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin.

.zshrc
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
# Gem
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
export GEM_PATH="$HOME/.gem"
### PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$(rbenv root)/shims:$(rbenv root)/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.gem/bin:$PATH"

~» gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/rege/.gem
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/rege/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/rege/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/rege/.gem
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/rege/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
     - /Users/rege/.gem/bin
     - /Users/rege/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/rege/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/rege/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin

myproject(development)» which bundle
/Users/rege/.gem/bin/bundle
```

Comment: How to remove setting for installing gems into ./vendor/bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

check for your active gemset `rbenv gemset active`, maybe you are reffering a wrong gemset. To check for available gemlist trigger this `rbenv gemset list`

Comment: I don't have gemset plugin and don't want to